Is there a closed formula for this sum?
The sum is $$f_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$
I figured I need a closed formula for this or for the cosine of this whole expression in order to get a polar representation for that spiral thing that you construct with ruler and compass, I forgot the name of it. I also think it's easier to represent $$a_{n}=\cos(f_{n})$$ because there is a relation:
$$a_{n}= \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\left(a_{n-1}\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1-a_{n-1}²}\right)$$
So solving this reccurence relation would also be good as a solution.

Mathjax: for standard functions like cos please use \cos to get $\cos$ instead of cos which gives an awkward looking $cos$.

I doubt that there is a closed formula, but see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2788711/42969 for an approximation.

Yeah that's exactly the question I was trying to solve, unfortunately, I couldn't find a closed form for it and if there is no such than I guess approximation is the best I can get.

Can be expressed by integral: $$\sum _{k=1}^n \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-((1+n) x)} \left(-1+e^{n x}\right)
\text{erfi}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{2 \left(-1+e^x\right) x} , dx$$

I found an alternative expression that might or might not help you:
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=0}^n\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt k}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt k}\right)&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m\geq 0}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{2m+1}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt k}\right)^m\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{m\geq 0}\dfrac{(-1)^m}{2m+1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{k^{m+\frac{1}{2}}}\right]\\
&=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+\sum_{m\geq 0}\dfrac{(-1)^m 
 H^{(m+\frac{1}{2})}_n}{2m+1}
\end{aligned}$$
where $H^{(m+\frac{1}{2})}_n$ is a generalized harmonic number.

Otherwise, you could take the cosine of $f_n$:
Let's employ rotation matrices:
$$\begin{aligned}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(f_n) & -\sin(f_n)\\
\sin(f_n) & \cos(f_n)
\end{pmatrix}&=\prod_{k=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
c_k & -s_k\\ 
s_k & c_k
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^n s_k\cdot \prod_{k=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt k & -1\\ 
1 & \sqrt k
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}} \prod_{k=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt k & -1\\ 
1 & \sqrt k
\end{pmatrix},
\end{aligned}$$
where we used the fact that $s_k\equiv \sin\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\right)\right]=\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+k}}$ and $c_k\equiv \cos\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\right)\right]=\sqrt{\frac{k}{1+k}}=\sqrt k\, s_k$.
Now taking the trace on both sides we can find $\cos(f_n)$:
$$\cos(f_n)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(n+1)!}} \mathrm{tr}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt k & -1\\ 
1 & \sqrt k
\end{pmatrix}\right)$$
What's left is finding the product of these $k$th matrices.
Notice we now have an expression for $f_n$ if we take the $\arccos$ and add some suitable factor.

I guess you made a typo in the first line, since $\arctan\frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan x$. Nevertheless, great ideas ! +1

According to this result, we have then:
$$\begin{align}
f_n&=\arccos \left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(n+1)!}} \underbrace{\mathrm{tr}\left(\prod_{k=0}^n\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt k & -1\
1 & \sqrt k
\end{pmatrix}\right)}{=\prod{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right) + \prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i}\right)} \right) \
&= \arccos \left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(n+1)!}}\left( \prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}+ \mathbf{i}\right) + \prod_{k=0}^n\left(\sqrt{k}- \mathbf{i}\right)\right) \right)
\end{align}$$

I was able to find a good close formula approximation.
let's say that $g(n)=f(n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
from that:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=\lim_{d->0}
\frac{g(x+d)-g(x)}{d}\approx g(x+1)-g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)=\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}})$$
Using an integral calculator we get:
$$
g(x)=\int_0^xarctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}}\right)dt=\sqrt{x+1}+x*\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\right)
-2*\arctan\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)+c
$$
It's not too hard to prove that there is $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that$|g(x)-f(x)|<M$ for each $x>1$.
For $c=1$ the approximation is very good, so:
$$
f_n\approx\sqrt{x+1}+x*\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}\right)
-2*\arctan\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)+1$$
